# Does IE6 support XMLHttpRequest.abort()?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

Am I correct to understand that the abort() method for XMLHttpRequest objects is only available starting from MSIE 7? If so, what equivalent option do I have for aborting an XMLHttpRequest object on timeout in MSIE 6?

Using a JS framework to abstract the problem away is not an option at this time I'm afraid :(. I'm on a legacy system that's close to a production deadline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On IE6, you instantiate the MSXML HTTPRequest manually, so it all comes down to what version you end up using.

abort is [implemented in MSXML 3.0 and later](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760349(VS.85).aspx). In other words, if you can get this or a later version instantiated (rather than 2.0 or 2.6), you can use abort.

To the best of my knowledge, IE6 should use MSXML 3.0 when nothing else is specified (http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx seems to confirm this), so it *should* work out of the box - but I can't test this right now, as I don't have access to an IE6 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look to a framework like jQuery for doing http requests with javascript. They nicely abstract away browser differences.

Comment: A framework is not an option at this time I'm afraid :(. I'm on a legacy system that's close to a production deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that IE does not support XMLHttpRequest really, but Microsoft.XMLHTTP and various related flavours, the answer is abort is available depending on the instantiated object I believe.

[This](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_a_1.html) article and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810120748/http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/03/07/71625.aspx) article might help you with the problem your having.